# Android issue uploading image to server using Axios in React-Native App

Tags: android, react-native, multipartform-data, axios, form-data

I am getting the following network error when attempting to upload/POST an image from Android. Works perfectly on iOS. Works perfectly on Android when no image included in FormData.

```
export function formatAvatarData(uri) {
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('avatar', {
    uri: uri,
    type: 'file',
    name: 'image.jpg',
  });
  return form;
}
```

iOS - [THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED]
uri: `file:///Users/bobfriston/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/16E84C5E-2545-408C-B870-38054DFA3471/data/Containers/Data/Application/7D2F59E5-450A-4A60-962A-D5C368DCD8DF/Documents/images/F5AD02D9-6C3E-46E5-B54E-D5C98206BAAA.jpg`

ANDROID URI - [THIS GIVES NETWORK ERROR AS BELOW]
uri: `content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F79/ORIGINAL/NONE/1408072274`

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:542)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:378)
```

NOTES:
"react-native": "=0.42.3"

AndroidManifest.xml has these permissions included:

```
android.permission.INTERNET"
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
android.permission.CAMERA" />
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try to change `type` to `image/jpeg`:

```
export function formatAvatarData(uri) {
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('avatar', {
    uri: uri,
    type: 'image/jpeg', // <-- this
    name: 'image.jpg',
  });
  return form;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm that the `type` that raise `Network Error` on Android

Comment: Have you got any solutions?

I'm facing issue since 4 days and no updates.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem is here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7306#issue-151988731

Answer (score 0):

The below steps helped me resolve the same issue. Just in case helps,

1. In android/app/src/main/java/com/{yourProject}/MainApplication.java
   comment the below line :

   ```
   initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())
   ```
2. In android/app/src/debug/java/com/{yourProject}/ReactNativeFlipper.java
   comment line 43 :

   ```
   builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
   ```
3. Code for image upload :

   ```
   var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('UserId', 'abc@abc.com');
      formData.append('VisitId', '28596');
      formData.append('EvidenceCapturedDate', '09/10/2019 13:28:20');
      formData.append('EvidenceCategory', 'Before');
      formData.append('EvidenceImage', {
        uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? `file:///${path}` : `/private${path}`,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'image.jpg',
      });
      axios({
        url: UrlString.BaseUrl + UrlString.imageUpload,
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log('*****handle success******');
          console.log(response.data);

        })
        .catch(function (response) {
          console.log('*****handle failure******');
          console.log(response);
        });
   ```